# Toggling digital signing in Outlook.MailItem

Tags: outlook, signing, smime, mailitem

In Outlook 2007, I have written an Application_ItemSend handler which needs to turn off digital signing for selected messages, even though signing is normally on by default for all messages.

How can I activate/deactivate signing for MailItem objects?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932308/encrypt-outlook-mail-programmatically-via-vba

Answer (score 1):

> *There is an old technique of hooking the buttons and calling execute...*

I'm not sure if it helps, but if you're hooking buttons, the idMso of those toggle buttons are "DigitallySignMessage" and "EncryptMessage" from the GroupRightsManagement tab of the Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taliking about outlook digital signing I dont think it can be done via the OOM.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. How else could it be done, then?

Comment: The Api does not expose this :( . There is an old technique of hooking the buttons and calling execute (very hacky but thats how you got pre ol2003 to anything) In ol2003 there were "Sign" and "Encrypt" Buttons but I cannot see those button in any toolbar in 2007 do you know if the exist ?