# Send Outlook maiItem with Encrypt-Only permission vb.net or powershell

Tags: vb.net, encryption, outlook, permissions, mailmessage

I need send email message via Outlook with permission Encrypt-Only via VB.net or PowerShell.
Permission Encrypt-Only became available in 2018 in Office 365.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-privacy-and-compliance/encrypt-only-rolling-out-starting-today-in-office-365-message/ba-p/162718

Microsoft.Interop have MailItem.Permission property with olDoNotForward (Item cannot be forwarded), olPermissionTemplate (for custom permission templates) and olUnrestricted (Item has no permission restrictions). Encrypt-Only is not a custom template.

Search in other libraries and API's results did not yield.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932308/encrypt-outlook-mail-programmatically-via-vba ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case that I need. I need exactly Encrypt-Only from IRM.