# IPM.Note.Secure vs IPM.Note.SMIME

Tags: outlook, mapi

Anyone knows what are these 2 here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes

IPM.Note.Secure :: Encrypted notes to other people

IPM.Note.Secure.Sign :: Digitally signed notes to other people

I mean secure email messages have these 2 IPMs:

IPM.Note.SMIME, IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned

I don't think that sticky notes can be signed or encrypted? (or I'm wrong?) So what are Note.Secure and Note.Secure.Sign?
Thanks

Comment: What do you see for these messages in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button, then IMAPISecureMessage as Outlook wraps encrypted/signed messages as regular mail items)?

Answer (score 0):

These are standard message classes in Outlook that belong to mail items, not sticky notes as you could think.

- `IPM.Note` - Normal e-mail message.
- `IPM.Note.SMIME` - The message is encrypted and can also be signed.
- `IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned` - The message is clear signed.
- `IPM.Note.Receipt.SMIME` - The message is a secure read receipt.

But the following message classes belongs to notes:

- `IPM.Note.Secure` - Encrypted notes to other people
- `IPM.Note.Secure.Sign` - Digitally signed notes to other people.

From the MAPI point of view every items is considered to be sent. Outlook applies its own business rules the low-level code. See [Item Types and Message Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes) for more information.

Also you may find the [2.2.2.49 MessageClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-asemail/51d84da6-a2da-41e9-8ca7-eb6c4e72c28d) section for more information about possible variations and their meanings.

Comment: Hello and thanks, but AFAIK Notes cannot be signed or encrypted, so please advise how to sign or encrypt a note in Outlook so it gets IPM.Note.Secure or IPM.Note.Secure.Sign class?

Comment: You can try to set the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS property like explained on the [Encrypt Outlook Mail Programmatically via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932308/encrypt-outlook-mail-programmatically-via-vba) thread.